# Angular - How to reload only router-outlet and not entire component/module

Tags: angular

I have an AppModule that lazyload businessModule after a successful authentication.
the entry component of this sub-module has a topbar, navbar, and router-outlet;

THE PROBLEM:
whenever I click a route it will re-render the entire module so ngOnInit is beeing called
for the topbar, navbar and the router-outlet current active component.

I'm trying to trigger the refresh ONLY to the router-outlet(child);
how can it be done ?

== Business Component (entryComponent) =

```
<div class="viewport businessMainGrid" style="overflow: auto;">
    <ng-container *ngIf="admin$ | async" class="fullspan">
        <h3 class="adminBack">
            <button (click)="toBizSide()">BACK TO ADMIN</button>
        </h3>
    </ng-container>

    <header>
        <app-topbar class="w-100 topbar"></app-topbar>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <app-navigation></app-navigation>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <span class="chatArea">
            <app-chat-bubble></app-chat-bubble>
        </span>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
</div>
```

= Sub-Module RouterModule =

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: BusinessComponent,

        children: [
            {
                path: 'chat',

                data: { name: 'chat' },
                canActivate: [BusinessModuleAccessGuard],
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import('../Chat/chat.module').then((m) => m.ChatModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'social',

                data: { name: 'social' },
                canActivate: [BusinessModuleAccessGuard],
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import('../Social/social.module').then(
                        (m) => m.SocialModule
                    ),
            },

            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                loadComponent: () =>
                    import('./Dashboard/business-dashboard.component').then(
                        (m) => m.BusinessDashboardComponent
                    ),
            },

            {
                path: 'profile',
                component: ProfileComponent,
            },

            {
                path: '**',
                redirectTo: 'dashboard',
            },
        ],
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [BusinessModuleAccessGuard],
})
export class BusinessRoutingModule {}
```

=Navbar Component=

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let sidebarnavItem of sidebarnavItems">
        <li class="mb-3" (click)="addActiveClass(sidebarnavItem.title)"
            [routerLink]="sidebarnavItem.path !== '' ? [sidebarnavItem.path] : null">


            <a class="sidebar-link waves-effect waves-dark">
                <i [style.display]="'block'"><img class="icon" [src]="sidebarnavItem.icon" alt="settings"></i>

            </a>

            <h3 class="m-0 mini-title ">{{sidebarnavItem.title}}</h3>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
```

[image: Desired Result]

I've tried numerous things such as loading route via with no success

```
let url = this.router.url;
            
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
                this.router.navigate([`/${url}`]);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a `businessService` injected to the dashboard component which had a `shouldReuseRoute` set to false on it's constructor.

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
```